# Resize window in multi-thread ncurses program

Tags: signals, multithreading, ncurses

The overall question is simple:

How to gracefully resize a window in a multi-thread ncurses program?

---

Details here. I have read a few relevant questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707137/ncurses-resizing-glitch), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294134/python-curses-terminal-resize-issue), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717192/ncurses-and-resizing-window)). From my understanding, there are basically 2 ways to handle a window resize:

1. Call `endwin` followed by `refresh` in user's own `SIGWINCH` handler.
2. Leverage ncurses builtin `SIGWINCH` handler: `getch` a `KEY_RESIZE` and handle it.

I have tested on my ncurses implementation to make sure I can receive `KEY_RESIZE`. But I still don't understand how signal handler works with multi-thread ncurses program:

1. If I'm using the builtin `SIGWINCH` handler, which thread will be running the signal handler? Does this matter? Do I have control over this?
2. The builtin `SIGWINCH` handler generates a `KEY_RESIZE`. But what if there are other keys pressed that haven't been delivered? Is `KEY_RESIZE` guaranteed to be the key returned by the next call of `getch`?
3. Handling `KEY_RESIZE` looks less painful than writing my own `SIGWINCH` handler. But how can I read this key as soon as it is delivered to make the UI responsive? Can I select or poll stdin to detect its delivery? Is it put on an internal queue that only has something to do with `getch` but nothing to do with stdin?
4. If I'm writing my own `SIGWINCH` handler, do I have any guarantee about ncurses context so that my signal handler code won't break ncurses (by calling functions that cannot be called at the time the signal is delivered, etc.)?
5. Is ncurses itself single-threaded or multi-threaded? If I block the `SIGWINCH` signal on all my threads other than the main thread, am I guaranteed to receive the `SIGWINCH` signal on the main thread (but not an internal thread created by the ncurses library)?

Answer (score 2):

That's several questions.  Briefly:

- ncurses is single-threaded.
- ncurses [can be configured](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-5.7.html) (build-time) to improve its re-entrancy and add some functions which simplify using mutex's on its structures.  But most packagers do not use the feature.  A few of the ncurses example programs demonstrate the feature.
- most implementations of curses (i.e., anything newer than 35 years) lets you call `wgetch` either nonblocking or with a very short timeout.
- `KEY_RESIZE` is treated specially (on the same *FIFO* as character input, and not affected by the [`keypad`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) setting, as noted in the [`wgetch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) manual page).
- unless you're using an ncurses configuration with the (rudimentary!) support for threaded applications (and working within ***its*** limitations), all of ncurses input/output should be on a single thread.  Your other threads can do what they want.
- ncurses uses a static (persistent/global) variable for recording that a signal arrive.  That probably eliminates potential problems with a signal arriving on a different thread than the one which set up the handler.  But as suggested [here](https://devarea.com/linux-handling-signals-in-a-multithreaded-application/#.YTaiCMYpBpg), you may find a bug.